# C# to NodeJS APi - Correct workflow of Token and Refresh Token

Tags: node.js, refresh-token

I have created a C# application connecting to a MYSQL DB via NodeJS API. (all written by myself).

I'm learning this and I'm trying to get the most secure way of organising the Token and Refresh Token.

Currently I just have the API token with no expiry, so I'm implementing:

- 5 min token
- 1 year ref token

My confusion lies with the workflow. Two options I can fathom:

**1. Don't use Ref token in header "always":**

- Send Token for a request.
- Token Expired - response to app
- App sends refresh token
- check refresh token exists (in mysql)
- check refresh is not expired
- New token created, sent back to app.
- App now sends the token for the initial request.

**2. Send ref token in header always:**

- Send token and refresh for a request.
- If token expired, check for refresh (error on no refresh)
- check refresh token exists (in mysql)
- check refresh is not expired
- New token created
- run the request using the newly generated token
- return original request response but with the new access token connected

Now the Option 1 seems... like every time there is a new token generation I'm looking at 3 calls to the server.
The benefit is that the request doesn't always have that refresh key in it

Option 2 is all based in Node JS, but it means every request response would have something like

```
{ newTokenCreated: True,
newToken: 123345456567567567,
actualRequestResponse: blahblah }
```

I'm unsure what is the best way to do this as I have half written the Option 2, but to a degree option 1 seems more appropriate except then every time a token is expired there are then 3 calls just to get the new token from the API, instead of option 2 which is just one call and the app really doesnt have to do that much think, just check if it got given a new access token!

Thanks for any advice.  I've watched about 10 youtube videos but can't seem to get this bit down.

Answer (score -1):

In our application, we always send the authorization token in the authorization field, whenever authorization is required.
Below is the sample request headers:

```
:authority: 24n3z33o7e.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
:method: GET
:path: /dev/user/profile
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,kn;q=0.8
authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYxZjRmNGE2ODIxNWVhMDAwOTg2Y2UwZiIsImlhdCI6MTY0NTUwOTYzNSwiZXhwIjoxNjQ1NTEwNTM1fQ.5PcJPNliuYO0n3RTD0gjWwPZ3wW_MQsug0gP0Tr9B9Q
content-type: application/json
if-none-match: W/"a8a-NVC3K4F3Ht14zY2oA/6nJxM78uo"
locale: en
origin: https://spark.dynasty-dev.com
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Google Chrome";v="98"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.80 Safari/537.36
```

The authorization field contains the token.
We also follow the work flow option 1 where we 'Don't use Ref token in header "always":'.

Our work flow followed:[image]

1. Send token in request headers.
2. Token Expired - response from app.
3. User needs to login again.
4. Once user will successfully login, App sends new token
5. User will use this for further API calls with authorization

Comment: Thanks Krishna, But do you use refresh tokens? Because this is the main question I am checking on.